# Como "setar" focus em uma função onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, react

Como eu faço para deixar um elemento focado ao clicar nele?

**exemplo**

No momento eu estou fazendo uma pagina de filtro que tem alguns botões, porem esses botões so funcionam se eu clicar duas vezes. (A função onClick dentro deles recebe um handle, que seta o useState para true e executa uma const para ordenar os contatos e lidar com os filtros criados). Funciona normalmente, porem eu preciso clicar duas vezes.

Acredito que o primeiro click esta sendo o focus e o segundo sim esta setando e executando.

Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer isso. Coloco algo dentro do handle? Crio uma função a parte e coloco dentro de um onFocus?

Comment: Já penou em utilizar o evento [`dbclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event)? No JSX, a propriedade chama-se `onDoubleClick`.

Answer (score 0):

Sem o código fica meio difícil de entender o que você deseja fazer, se puder colocar o código ajuda bastante a comunidade a te ajudar.